# Android UDP client cant receive data from remote server

Tags: android, sockets, udp

In my simple client server application we have a case that is client not able to receive packets from server. If the server and clients are in same LAN then system working perfectly. If we put server on internet then clients are able send data but cant receive from server. Of course we know that in this architecture both clients has same ip address which is assigned from ISP from server viewpoint. So how can server able send packet to some local network with separating different machines.
[image]

Comment: No. Then both clients do not have the same ip address. Your router has an ip address assigned from ISP. And your clients have different LAN ip addresses assigned by the router. You should care that the router forwards UTP packets to both clients.

Comment: I said that same ip address but i also said that "from server viewpoint" of course clients have different ip's on same LAN. So we are on same page. If i have to configure router then this means this program can not be used LAN's which is not under my control!

Comment: You have to configure the router for Port Forwarding, where each client uses a different port on the router.  Then the server can send packets to the different ports. If the router supports uPNP and it is enabled, the clients can configure the router dynamically. Otherwise, the router admin has to configure the router. Or use NAT Traversal techniques, like UDP Hole Punching.

Comment: Thanks for comment but "If the router supports uPNP and it is enabled"  we can not accept conditional solution because of "Otherwise, the router admin has to configure the router" which we can't access or ask them. We were implementing a kind of VOIP system , UDP is perfect for stream transfers, but i found that even skype switch to TCP from UDP.